# Getting abbriviations from checkboxes when selected to be added to name outputs

Tags: javascript, html

in my form im trying to make a directory that will display the information that the user inputs. and in the .js file i posted below i have it setup as a var message = and it gives me my output of all data that was inputted. im wracking my brain on the code for when a person selects one of the checkedboxes for Dr. Mr. Mrs. Miss. how can i get it to show up before the first and last name when it is being displayed.  any input/ insight is greatly appreciated. sorry if its a simply solution still trying to figure out the whole javascript thing.

```
 <form action="#" method="post" id="directory">
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Department Directory</legend>
     <div class="tab">
        <div class="tRow">
           <div class="tCell"><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></div>
           <div class="tCell">&nbsp;</div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
           <div class="tCell"><label for="staff">Role:</label></div>
           <div class="tCell"><input type="radio" id="faculty" value="Faculty">Faculty<input type="radio" id="staff" value="Staff">Staff</div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
           <div class="tCell"><label for="dr">Doctorate?</label></div>
           <div class="tCell"><input type="checkbox" id="dr" value="dr">Dr.</div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
          <div class="tCell"><label for="first_name">first name:</label></div>
           <div class="tCell"><input type="text" id="first_name" required></div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
          <div class="tCell"><label for="last_name">last name:</label></div>
           <div class="tCell"><input type="text" id="last_name" required></div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
           <div class="tCell"><label for="cert">Certifications:</label></div>
           <div class="tCell"><input type="text" id="cert" required></div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
           <div class="tCell"><label for="title">Title:</label></div>
           <div class="tCell"><input type="text" id="title" required></div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
           <div class="tCell"><label for="department">Department:</label></div>
           <div class="tCell">
              <select id="department" required>
                 <option  selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Select one</option>
                 <option value="School of Information Technology">School of Information Technology</option>
                 <option value="School of Marketing">School of Marketing</option>
                 <option value="School of Aviation">School of Aviation</option>
              </select>
           </div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
           <div class="tCell"><label>Phone Number:</label></div>
           <div class="tCell">
            (<input type=tel size=3 id="tel1" maxlength=3 required>) <span style="font-weight:bold; color:red;" id="err1"></span><!--error tag-->
            <input type=tel size=3 id="tel2"  maxlength=3 required> - <span style="font-weight:bold; color:red;" id="err2"></span><!--error tag-->
            <input type=tel size=4 id="tel3" maxlength=4 required>    <span style="font-weight:bold; color:red;" id="err3"></span><!--error tag-->
          </div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
           <div class="tCell"><label for="website">Website:</label></div>
           <div class="tCell"><input type="url" id="website" required></div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
        <div class="tRow">
           <div class="tCell"><label for="email">E-mail:</label></div>
           <div class="tCell"><input type="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email Address"></div>
        </div><!--ROW STOPS-->
     </div><!--Table Stops-->
  </fieldset>
  <div id="output"></div>
```

```
function process() {
    // VARIABLES
    var faculty  = document.getElementById("faculty").value;
    var staff = document.getElementById("staff").value;
    var dr = document.getElementById("dr").value;
    var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var last_name = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var cert = document.getElementById("cert").value;
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var department = document.getElementById("department").value;
    var tel1 = document.getElementById("tel1").value;
    var tel2 = document.getElementById("tel2").value;
    var tel3 = document.getElementById("tel3").value;
    var website = document.getElementById("website").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    // Create a new object:
    var employee = {
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        cert: cert,
        title: title,
        department: department,
        email: email,
        phone: tel1 + tel2 + tel3,
        website: website,
    };
    console.log(employee);
    // Create the ouptut as HTML:
    var message = "<h2>Directory:</h2>" + employee.first_name + ", " + employee.last_name + "&nbsp;" + employee.cert + "<br>";
    message += employee.title + "<br>";
    message += employee.department + "<br>";
    message += "<a href='/"+ employee.email +"'>"+ employee.email +"</a><br>";
    message += "Phone: " + employee.phone + "<br>";
    message += "Website:" + "<a href='/"+ employee.website +"'>"+ employee.website +"</a><br>";
    // Display the employee object:
    output.innerHTML = message;        
    // Return false:
    return false;
} 
function init() { 
 // CLICK EVENT
     document.getElementById("directory").onsubmit = process;
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: `// Return false:` as a comment to "explain" the `return false;` statement? Really?